# ListView ItemContainerStyle Template

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I created style to be used as my ListView's item template that contains a CheckBox and a TextBlock:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
            <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Multiple"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" >
                        <Setter Property="Template">
...
```

The checkbox in the template is bound to the IsSelected property of the list view item:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="itemCheckBox" Width="13" Height="13" Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
```

And the textblock's text is bound to the Value property of the source of the list view item:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Padding="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Each of the items in my list is an object that contains two properties, **Value** and **IsChecked**.  What I am trying to do is bind the IsChecked property of my object to the IsSelected property of my list view item.  However, I do not know how to access the IsChecked property of my object from within the ListViewItem template.

I didn't have any trouble binding the content of the text block to the Value property of my object but where would I even put the binding definition if I want the IsChecked property of my object to be bound to the IsSelected property of the list view item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataContext for each ListViewItem should be set to the item data when it is created by the parent ListView so you should be able to use:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" >
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsChecked}">
    ...
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great.  Seems so simple now that I think about it.