# ComboBoxItem Will Not Collapse

Tags: wpf

I wrote a basic visibility converter such that when the property "Active" is true the ComboBoxItem should be Visible, Collapsed otherwise. It currently displays the Active ones properly, the inactive ones Text are invisible but the item can still be seen.

http://snag.gy/Mh2Xq.jpg

May I ask how do I get the ComboBoxItem to collapse the comboboxitem that are inactive properly please.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" SelectedItem="{Binding Product, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Active, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter }}"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Consider applying the visibility to the [ListViewItem][1] element.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043505/listview-itemcontainerstyle-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Visibility"  Value="{Binding Active, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the visibility converter to the parent stackpanel instead. Like so:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding Active, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
...
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: or remove the stackpanel +1

Comment: Hi, I tried both methods. I removed the stack panel And I tried putting converter to the parent but the same behavior persist.

Comment: I added a combo Box resources and it worked perfectly! Not quite sure why your method didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should filter the bound list on basis of IsActive

Try to Bind comboBox to

```
Products.Where(t => t.IsActive)
```

Comment: Sorry not quite what I wanted. I'm looking for the comboBox to Collapse

Comment: a tidy way is what I suggested, if you are using mvvm, filtering list in VM would keep your life easy :)